# Django's change password form (views.py)

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have an issue, I really don't know how to remove the help_text, label, or whatever it is in the change_password form views.py.
Look at the picture I linked for more information about ...

Code :

```
@login_required (login_url="/profilo/login/")
def password_change(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, user)  
            messages.success(request, 'Password cambiata con successo!')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/profilo/password_change/done/')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Errore !')
    else:
        form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user)
    context = { 'form' : form }
    return render(request, 'registration/password_change.html',context)
```

[image]
this is the picture, between the inputs you can see the text with markers, how can I remove it?

Comment: Please show some relevant code from your project. How are you using the change password views in your project?

Comment: Im using a classic password change views , like def pass_change(): update_session_auth_hash()... Like the documentation

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your actual code.

Comment: Can you provide the code of the `registration/password_change.html` file?